# Match a Pattern with REGEX with C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with one example

I need to build a pattern that match with the following:

- Example1 = `(and 'value1' 'value2' 'value3')` --> I need `value1`,`value2`,`value3` in a List.
- Example2 = `(and field1:'value1' field2:'value2' field3:'value3')` --> In this case the values should be omitted --> List should be **empty**
- Example3 = `(and((and field1:'value1' field2:'value2' 'value3')(and 'value100' value101))` --> List should contain `value3`,`value100`

So as sumarize, I need all words that match with \'.+\' but not math with .+:\'.+\'

- `'value'` --> value **should match**
- `field:'value'` --> value **should be omitted**

value and field could be anything

Comment: your examples are a little misleading. is `(and 'value1' 'value2' 'value3')` , `(and field1:'value1' field2:'value2' field3:'value3')`, and `(and((and field1:'value1' field2:'value2' 'value3')(and 'value100' value101)` strings?

Comment: where are you matchin this?=! in a string? in a list of strings?

Comment: I need to extract the values from one string... the string is an URL... URL generated by Amazon Cloud Search Service.

Comment: You are right... sorry 
i edit the request right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try direct pattern

```
(?<!:)'(?<value>\w+)'
```

where

```
'(?<value>\w+)' - alphanumeric letters within apostrophes
(?<!:)          - but NOT before ":"
```

I've put `\w+` instead of suggested `.+` since we *don't want* `' field2:'` matches

Something like this:

```
string source = 
  @"(and((and field1:'value1' field2:'value2' 'value3')(and 'value100' value101))";

string pattern = @"(?<!:)'(?<value>\w+)'";

List<string> items = Regex
  .Matches(source, pattern)
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Groups["value"].Value)
  .ToList();
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", items));
```

Outcome:

```
value3; value100
```

Comment: You are the guy!!!
all yours!!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Very abstract task. For this examples I can offer this issue:
"\s\'?value[0-9]+\'?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use negative lookbehind like this:

`\w*(?<!:)'value'`

Answer (score -1):

This is a great tool that lets you generate regex's using genetic algorithm.

You provide it with sample data sets and it will produce a regex that satisfies the data sets. The more data in the data sets (with edge cases etc.) the more accurate the final regex will be.

http://regex.inginf.units.it/

If you want to write the regex yourself you'll need to go and learn regex. There are tonnes of resources online for doing so.